# 'boost::archive::archive_exception' what(): unsupported version

Tags: serialization, boost

I cloned this repository:

```
https://github.com/srianant/computer_vision
```

built and ran,got this error:

```
OpenPose/DLIB Gesture, Action and Face Recognition.
resolution: 640x480
net_resolution: 656x368
handNetInputSize: 368x368
face_net_resolution: 368x368
cCamera Resolution set to: 640x480
Push following keys:
p for pause sample generation
f for generating face samples
t for train samples
c for continue camera feed
h for display key commands
q for quit program
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::archive::archive_exception'
  what():  unsupported version
```

And this exception thrown from this file:line:32

```
https://github.com/srianant/computer_vision/blob/master/openpose/src/openpose/user_code/pose_model.cpp
```

I think it is trying to deserialized this file:

```
https://github.com/srianant/computer_vision/blob/master/openpose/train_data/pose/pose.model
```

Comment: What is a "bin file", did you make it, what version of boost does your program link, how did you get the archive file/data, what do you mean "gotten from provide". Then: "boost" does not necessarily generate a specific version. There's archive format versioning (but no binary archives aren't portable anyways) but there's also class versioning for serialization. You will have to be a -lot- more specific with this question to get any kind of useful information back. Meanwhile I'd look at the documentation to find out more.

Comment: You can probably [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47120076/edit), fixing the spelling errors and adding the information. You might even add the link to that repository that somehow didn't appear here either. What steps are you doing after cloning the repo that don't work? (Is there an archive file inside the repository?)|

Comment: @ago,I updated my question

Comment: That cpp file is clearly not the file you were looking for, and my name is @sehe :) By the way, the `*.model` are "Keras RNN LSTM Classifier model" files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After replacing ::archive 14 with ::archive 12 in all txt files,this problem gone,@sehe thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You're probably doing something wrong: have you checked your boost version? It could just be (very) old.

I can deserialize all the input archives that use boost.

The only use of boost is in `openpose_recognition.cpp`, and the only archives being read are text archives from the training data.

It is easy to create a standalone program to verify that these file can be deserialized.

### Creating The Minimal Declarations

Extracted from pose_model.hpp:

```
// Timesteps per samples
const int timesteps = 5; // 5 frames per sample

// 2-dim data to store different postures
const int max_pose_count = 10;
const int max_pose_score_pair = 36;  // 34 pairs for pose + 2 padding for multiples of 4
typedef std::array<std::string, max_pose_count> pose;
typedef std::array<double,max_pose_score_pair*timesteps> pose_sample_type;

// 2-dim data to store different hand actions
const int max_hand_count = 10;
const int max_hand_score_pair = 40;  // 40 pairs for hand
typedef std::array<std::string,max_hand_count> hand;
typedef std::array<double,max_hand_score_pair*timesteps> hand_sample_type;

// 2-dim data to store different faces
const int max_face_count = 10;
const int max_face_score_pair = 96; // 96 pairs (94 + 2 pairs for padding for multiples of 4)
typedef std::array<std::string,max_face_count> face;
typedef std::array<double,max_face_score_pair*timesteps> face_sample_type;
```

### Test Method:

All extractions follow the same pattern, let's add a `debug_print` method later:

```
template <typename T>
void read_and_verify(std::string name, T& into) {
    std::ifstream ifs("/tmp/so/computer_vision/openpose/train_data/" + name);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> into;

    debug_print(name, into);
}
```

> **Note**: Adjust the path to match your file locations

### Reading All The Archives:

```
int main() {
    {
        pose pose_names;
        std::vector<pose_sample_type> pose_samples; // vector of m_pose_sample vectors
        std::vector<double> pose_labels;            // vector of pose labels (eg. 1,2,3...)

        read_and_verify("pose/pose_names.txt", pose_names);
        read_and_verify("pose/pose_samples.txt", pose_samples);
        read_and_verify("pose/pose_labels.txt", pose_labels);
    }

    {
        face face_names;                            // vector of face emotions names (eg. normal, sad, happy...)
        std::vector<face_sample_type> face_samples; // vector of m_face_sample vectors
        std::vector<double> face_labels;            // vector of face emotions labels (eg. 1,2,3...)
        read_and_verify("face/face_names.txt", face_names);
        read_and_verify("face/face_samples.txt", face_samples);
        read_and_verify("face/face_labels.txt", face_labels);
    }

    {
        hand hand_names;                                    // vector of hand gesture names (eg. fist, victory, stop...);
        std::vector<hand_sample_type> left_hand_samples;    // vector of m_left_hand_sample vectors
        std::vector<hand_sample_type> right_hand_samples;   // vector of m_right_hand_sample vectors
        std::vector<double> left_hand_labels;               // vector of left hand labels (eg. 1,2,3...)
        std::vector<double> right_hand_labels;              // vector of right hand labels (eg. 1,2,3...)
        read_and_verify("hand/hand_names.txt", hand_names);
        read_and_verify("hand/left_hand_samples.txt", left_hand_samples);
        read_and_verify("hand/right_hand_samples.txt", right_hand_samples);
        read_and_verify("hand/left_hand_labels.txt", left_hand_labels);
        read_and_verify("hand/right_hand_labels.txt", right_hand_labels);
    }
}
```

### Printing Debug Info:

We need only three different `debug_print` overloads, for names, samples and labels:

```
template <size_t N> // names
void debug_print(std::string name, std::array<std::string, N> const& data) {
    std::cout << name << ": ";

    for (auto& n : data)
        if (!n.empty())
            std::cout << n << " ";

    std::cout << "\n";
}

// labels
void debug_print(std::string name, std::vector<double> const& data) {
    std::cout << name << ": ";

    for (auto& a : data)
        std::cout << a << " ";

    std::cout << "\n";
}

template <size_t N> // samples
void debug_print(std::string name, std::vector<std::array<double, N> > const& data) {
    std::cout << name << ": ";

    for (auto& a : data)
        std::cout << "{" << a[0] << "...} ";

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

### DEMO TIME

The complete program is here:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/003bd4eda410473e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

///////////////// from pose_model.hpp
//
    // Timesteps per samples
    const int timesteps = 5; // 5 frames per sample

    // 2-dim data to store different postures
    const int max_pose_count = 10;
    const int max_pose_score_pair = 36;  // 34 pairs for pose + 2 padding for multiples of 4
    typedef std::array<std::string, max_pose_count> pose;
    typedef std::array<double,max_pose_score_pair*timesteps> pose_sample_type;

    // 2-dim data to store different hand actions
    const int max_hand_count = 10;
    const int max_hand_score_pair = 40;  // 40 pairs for hand
    typedef std::array<std::string,max_hand_count> hand;
    typedef std::array<double,max_hand_score_pair*timesteps> hand_sample_type;

    // 2-dim data to store different faces
    const int max_face_count = 10;
    const int max_face_score_pair = 96; // 96 pairs (94 + 2 pairs for padding for multiples of 4)
    typedef std::array<std::string,max_face_count> face;
    typedef std::array<double,max_face_score_pair*timesteps> face_sample_type;
//
///////////////// end pose_model.hpp

template <size_t N> // names
void debug_print(std::string name, std::array<std::string, N> const& data) {
    std::cout << name << ": ";

    for (auto& n : data)
        if (!n.empty())
            std::cout << n << " ";

    std::cout << "\n";
}

// labels
void debug_print(std::string name, std::vector<double> const& data) {
    std::cout << name << ": ";

    for (auto& a : data)
        std::cout << a << " ";

    std::cout << "\n";
}

template <size_t N> // samples
void debug_print(std::string name, std::vector<std::array<double, N> > const& data) {
    std::cout << name << ": ";

    for (auto& a : data)
        std::cout << "{" << a[0] << "...} ";

    std::cout << "\n";
}

template <typename T>
void read_and_verify(std::string name, T& into) {
    std::ifstream ifs("/tmp/so/computer_vision/openpose/train_data/" + name);
    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(ifs);
    ia >> into;

    debug_print(name, into);
}

int main() {
    {
        pose pose_names;
        std::vector<pose_sample_type> pose_samples; // vector of m_pose_sample vectors
        std::vector<double> pose_labels;            // vector of pose labels (eg. 1,2,3...)

        read_and_verify("pose/pose_names.txt", pose_names);
        read_and_verify("pose/pose_samples.txt", pose_samples);
        read_and_verify("pose/pose_labels.txt", pose_labels);
    }

    {
        face face_names;                            // vector of face emotions names (eg. normal, sad, happy...)
        std::vector<face_sample_type> face_samples; // vector of m_face_sample vectors
        std::vector<double> face_labels;            // vector of face emotions labels (eg. 1,2,3...)
        read_and_verify("face/face_names.txt", face_names);
        read_and_verify("face/face_samples.txt", face_samples);
        read_and_verify("face/face_labels.txt", face_labels);
    }

    {
        hand hand_names;                                    // vector of hand gesture names (eg. fist, victory, stop...);
        std::vector<hand_sample_type> left_hand_samples;    // vector of m_left_hand_sample vectors
        std::vector<hand_sample_type> right_hand_samples;   // vector of m_right_hand_sample vectors
        std::vector<double> left_hand_labels;               // vector of left hand labels (eg. 1,2,3...)
        std::vector<double> right_hand_labels;              // vector of right hand labels (eg. 1,2,3...)
        read_and_verify("hand/hand_names.txt", hand_names);
        read_and_verify("hand/left_hand_samples.txt", left_hand_samples);
        read_and_verify("hand/right_hand_samples.txt", right_hand_samples);
        read_and_verify("hand/left_hand_labels.txt", left_hand_labels);
        read_and_verify("hand/right_hand_labels.txt", right_hand_labels);
    }
}
```

Printing (lines truncated at 100 characters):

```
pose/pose_names.txt: unknown close_to_camera standing sitting 
pose/pose_samples.txt: {204.658...} {196.314...} {210.322...} {191.529...} {192.8...} {187.155...} {...
pose/pose_labels.txt: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
face/face_names.txt: unknown normal happy sad surprise 
face/face_samples.txt: {89.5967...} {93.7026...} {97.6529...} {91.7247...} {91.8048...} {91.3076...}...
face/face_labels.txt: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
hand/hand_names.txt: unknown fist pinch wave victory stop thumbsup 
hand/left_hand_samples.txt: {0...} {0.000524104...} {0...} {0...} {0...} {0...} {0...} {0...} {0...}...
hand/right_hand_samples.txt: {0...} {0.00166845...} {0.00161618...} {0.00176376...} {0.00167096...} ...
hand/left_hand_labels.txt: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1...
hand/right_hand_labels.txt: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

### BONUS:

I had to use a hack to circumvent the file-size limit on Coliru: I changed to code to read bzip2 compressed files:

```
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/bzip2.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>

template <typename T>
void read_and_verify(std::string name, T& into) {
    std::ifstream compressed("/tmp/so/computer_vision/openpose/train_data/" + name + ".bz2");

    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream fs;
    fs.push(boost::iostreams::bzip2_decompressor{});
    fs.push(compressed);

    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(fs);
    ia >> into;

    debug_print(name, into);
}
```

Now you can actually see the output **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f01b7244afca5b2f)</kbd>**

Comment: ,thank you so much for your answer,your code in my laptop still gives:"boost::archive::archive_exception
  what():  unsupported version",and "sudo updatedb & sudo locate boost|grep seria|grep usr|grep so" finds:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_serialization.so.1.58.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_wserialization.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_wserialization.so.1.58.0,and 1st,3rd soft linked to 2nd,4th repectively,and the repository owner said he used boost.158.0.1(assume==1.58.0),any tips for further debugging?